# Visual Studio 2017 - Unable to generate class diagram from existing code

Tags: uml, visual-studio-2017, class-diagram

I have created a .NET Core server project that has a lot of classes. I need to generate a class diagram UML, and when I look on the Microsoft documentation site (I think it is only for vs2015), it tells me to click on the "Architecture" menu and click "Add New Diagram", but I couldn't find this button or function anywhere.

Is this function not supported anymore, or have they just not added this function yet? All the forums kept reporting it as a bug, but there's no workaround stated in the forums.

I am open to suggestions. Also I am using VS Enterprise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly Microsoft removed this functionality in VS 2017. 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/10/14/uml-designers-have-been-removed-layer-designer-now-supports-live-architectural-analysis/